# can Arduino subscribe to Firebase Cloud message notifications

Tags: firebase, arduino, firebase-cloud-messaging, arduino-esp8266

I have seen everywhere how to send FCM(firebase cloud messaging) notifications from Arduino through different libraries.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to make Arduino subscribe to a notification topic and handle incoming FCM.

The reason i want this is because my mobile app has the ability to change/update certain data(flags) in my realtime database, but it's not that often, so i dont want my Arduino to keep looking for changes in the firebase realtime database.. instead, i want it to just subscribe for notifications and receive an FCM notification whenever anything has changed on the app level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an Android device (any device) doesn't have Play services installed, then it can't receive FCM messages.  See the [documentation on what's required for various Firebase products](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services#play-services-required-summary) - FCM absolutely requires Play services.

Google typically requires that device manufacturers observe certain requirements for a device that wants Play services preloaded.  If it's not a consumer device, it almost certainly is not installed.  Perhaps you can try to install it yourself - start with a web search on that.